# How to get a query from criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria, seam2

I'm using `Seam 2.2.0.GA` with `JPA 1.2` provided by `Hibernate 3.3`. Is there a way to obtain an object of either `org.hibernate.Query` or `javax.persistence.Query` class out of a `org.hibernate.Criteria` query? Have the Criteria query as a EjbQL query string would also be acceptable for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Criteria queries are translated to SQL directly, without going through an intermediate JPQL/HQL query.

Comment: Is an object of `Query` class unobtainable too?

Comment: Yes. What would all the setParameter methods do on a Query obtained from a criteria?